# Create an instance of Action<'T> using reflection

Tags: reflection, f#, delegates

How would I create an instance of `Action<'T>` using reflection? Here's what I have:

```
let makeAction (typ:Type) (f:'T -> unit) = 
  let actionType = typedefof<Action<_>>.MakeGenericType(typ)
  let converter = FSharpFunc.ToConverter(f)
  Delegate.CreateDelegate(actionType, converter.Method)
```

which barfs with:

> System.ArgumentException: Error binding to target method.
>   at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type type, MethodInfo method, Boolean throwOnBindFailure)

`'T` is an interface, which `typ` implements.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to do this using reflection? As this can be done as simply as : `let makeAction (f: 'a -> unit) = new Action<'a>(f)`

Comment: @Ankur: Yes, because I don't know `'a` (in your example) at compile-time.

Comment: Not sure if I get you correctly, but the `'a` here is same as `'T` in your code i.e a generic type which is resolved depending on the the passed `f` value. You need a action type which wrap the passed `f` function right?

Comment: @Ankur: Regardless of the name, it's a type parameter which must be resolved at compile-time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are two problems. The first one is that you need to call `CreateDelegate` overload that takes three arguments. The additional argument specifies the instance on which the method should be invoked.

The second problem is that the `Converter<'T, unit>` actually compiles as a method that returns `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit` and not a method that returns `void`. I'm not sure if there is an easier workaround, but you can define a wrapper that has a method. Members are compiled to look like C#, so the unit type will be compiled as `void` in that case:

```
open System

type Wrapper<'T>(f:'T -> unit) =
  member x.Invoke(a:'T) = f a

let makeAction (typ:Type) (f:'T -> unit) = 
  let actionType = typedefof<Action<_>>.MakeGenericType(typ)
  let wrapperType = typedefof<Wrapper<_>>.MakeGenericType(typ)
  let wrapped = Wrapper<_>(f)
  Delegate.CreateDelegate(actionType, wrapped, wrapped.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke"))

makeAction (typeof<int>) (printfn "%d")
```

**EDIT** - Did a minor change to make it actually work in your scenario (with interface)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! I was only creating the `Converter` to get a `MethodInfo`. I wasn't sure how else to get it from an F# function.

Comment: @Daniel - If you have a function `f`, you can also use `f.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke")`, but that gives you a method that returns `unit`, so it won't work in this case.

Comment: Yeah, I attempted that first and made the same discovery.