# Create an action in F# in order to use a c# method

Tags: c#, f#

I would like to use this method from Owin implementation of HttpListener :

```
public static IDisposable Create(AppFunc app, IDictionary<string, object> properties)
```

AppFunc has a signature like this :

```ml
IDictionnary<string,Object> -> Task
```

I wanted to create a task but it requires an action, and I failed to know how to do it in F#.
The best I managed so far was  using the code in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836602/create-an-instance-of-actiont-using-reflection) :

```ml
module CsharpAction

open System

type Wrapper<'T>(f:'T -> unit) =
      member x.Invoke(a:'T) = f a

let makeAction (typ:Type) (f:'T -> unit) = 
    let actionType = typedefof<Action<_>>.MakeGenericType(typ)
    let wrapperType = typedefof<Wrapper<_>>.MakeGenericType(typ)
    let wrapped = Wrapper<_>(f)
    Delegate.CreateDelegate(actionType, wrapped, wrapped.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke"))
```

program.fs

```ml
let yymmdd1 (date:DateTime) = date.ToString("yy.MM.dd")
    let printSuccess = fun() -> printfn "Success %s" (yymmdd1 DateTime.Now )
    let actionTask = CsharpAction.makeAction (typeof<string>) (printSuccess)
    let mutable properties = Dictionary(dict [("fooKey", new Object())])


    let server = OwinServerFactory.Create((fun (props) -> new  Task(actionTask)) , properties)
```

but then it tells me : *this expression was expected to have type action but here has type delegate*

Should I give from F# an action to c# code? or should I work on the c# code in order to give f# some niceties , for instance waiting for delegate instead of action ?

I am flirting with the limits of my knowledge and I do feel the pain. Pretty sure, I will have to learn a lot, but if you would be so kind as to help me climb the first steps...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to use reflection to create delegates in F#. You can ditch the first part of your code altogether (your `CsharpAction` module).

As for the second chunk of code, try this:

```ml
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Threading.Tasks

let yymmdd1 (date : DateTime) = date.ToString "yy.MM.dd"
let printSuccess () = printfn "Success %s" (yymmdd1 DateTime.Now)

let server =
    let actionTask = Action printSuccess
    let properties = Dictionary (dict ["fooKey", obj ()])
    OwinServerFactory.Create((fun props -> new Task (actionTask)), properties)
```

Comment: Hi, I think the Action didn't got the props, it need to change to fun (props) -> new Task(printSuccess, props)

Comment: Sorry, my fault, it's different from my test, I trying to process the properties in Action when start the task

Comment: @Arthis `Action` isn't an F# keyword -- the way I've used it here, it's creating a `System.Action` delegate from the `printSuccess` function. In other words, it's like a constructor for a `System.Action` delegate.

Comment: mmmhh ok. This is one of the good thing I found while exploring F#. It is good to take another pov at c# and the .net ecosystem. Thanks for your input..