# How to use the C# action type in F#?

Tags: f#, action

I have this C# method:

```
public static IDisposable RegisterErrorHandler(Action<string, Exception> errorHandler)
```

How can I create the errorHandler in F#?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create an action in F# in order to use a c# method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802085/create-an-action-in-f-in-order-to-use-a-c-sharp-method)

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I had seen it because I didn't find the answer as clear as Tomas' answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F# will automatically convert lambda functions to delegate if they have the right types of arguments. In your case, you should be able to just provide a lambda function by writing:

```
Demo.RegisterErrorHandler(fun msg exn -> 
  printfn "Error with message %s and exception %A" msg exn)
```

Note that you need to write the two parameters as space separated rather than `(msg, exn)` which would indicate a tuple. Also, your lambda needs to return `unit` - otherwise the types won't match.

In cases where you cannot get this to work, it is useful to create the delegate explicitly. This will often make it easier to find out what's wrong with your lambda:

```
Demo.RegisterErrorHandler(Action<string, Exception>(fun msg exn -> 
  printfn "Error with message %s and exception %A" msg exn))
```

In most cases, you do not need explicit `Action` though.